# Inward radial force acting on falling water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws

A stream of water falling downward from a faucet has a decreasing radius due to conservation of mass compensating for the increase in velocity from gravity. What force gives the water an inward radial component of velocity so that it can flow inward?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surface tension will do it. Otherwise the stream would break into drops, as it does sometimes.